# R: How can I aggregate rows under conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to aggregate the variable `Schulbildung` which are less then 12. And aggregate the value of `n`. I tried using the `aggregate()` function but it didn't work. Has somebody any idea?

[image]

Comment: Hi there. Here is some information on creating a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Can you also show the code of what you've tried and what resulted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mutate with an `ifelse` statement to recode every value that is smaller than 12.
Summarise then with `dplyr`.

```
 df <- data.frame(
      Education = c(18, 16, 15, 12, 10, 8),
      entries = c(200, 100, 50, 50, 10 ,5)
    )
```

You said Education is a grouping varibale, so this means this is not the original data.frame, right?

```
df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Education = ifelse(Education < 12, "others", Education)) %>%
  group_by(Education) %>%
  summarise(entries = sum(entries))
```

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to mention that Education is a grouping variable, so I get the error: can't modify a grouping variable

Comment: use `ungroup` to get rid of the groups first.